# Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token in function definition

Tags: c++, templates

To keep things simple, lets say I have a Node class, each node has a Node* to another (previous ) node in a list. I want to create a getter function that, when called upon a Node, returns the pointer to the previous node.

However when I'm defining this function I get the aforementioned error message: `Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token`

Would really appreciate and advice!

Here's my Node class declaration:

```
template<typename NodeType>
class Node{

   public:
      ...
      Node* GetPrev();

   private:
     ...
      Node* _prev;

};
```

and implementation:

```
template <typename NodeType>
Node* Node<NodeType>::GetPrev()
{
   return _prev;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Node<NodeType>* Node<NodeType>::GetPrev()`.

Comment: oh thank you! 'could have sworn i'd tried that already but tried again and it compiled. Must have had a typo or something, cheers.